# Universal Render Pipeline | Текстура | Unity

Tags: unity3d, material-design, шейдеры

Подключил post-processing и теперь все мои материалы наследуются от Universal Render Pipeline. По-дефолту стоит Universal Render Pipeline\Lit, но проблема в том, что у этого шейдера нет текстуры. При попытке использовать Standard или т.п. появляется просто ErrorShader(фиолетовый цвет). Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

В самом шейдоре есть, подробнее посмотрите это видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OakD6vLj4uo

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]